# how to redirect from Normal java class to other java class which extends activity in android?

Tags: java, android

how to redirect from Normal java class to other java class which extends activity in android with putting some data.

Comment: Why is this question down voted? Better to improve the question or at least comment why you are downvoting.

Comment: thanks mek please do some needful if you have answer

Comment: @Chetak Bhimani you can use Intents is this what you're expecting ?

Comment: @Chetak I think your method in the normal class must accept Context as a parameter  `public void navigatorMethod(Context context) {...}`

Comment: Thanks mak i got your point i have to pass context ,it is done. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to start a Another activity class

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);//this your current class
startActivity(i);
```

to pass a value in class 1

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
i.putExtra("Value1", "This value one for ActivityTwo ");
i.putExtra("Value2", "This value two ActivityTwo");
```

to get values .from ActivityTwo.class

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras == null) {
  return;
}
// get data via the key
String value1 = extras.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
if (value1 != null) {
  // do something with the data
}
```